How do I use a local p2 generated repository?
To package an Eclipse plugin's update site, it used to be with packaging eclipse-update-site:
    <packaging>eclipse-update-site</packaging>

And once packaged, it could be used like this :
    <repository>
      <id>my-project</id>
      <name>My Project p2 repository</name>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>file:../path/to/project/target/site</url>
    </repository>

Now, packaging is eclipse-repository:
<packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>

Now it does not generate target/site anymore. It generates target/repository instead.
If I try to use the repository like this:
    <repository>
      <id>my-project</id>
      <name>My Project p2 repository</name>
      <layout>p2</layout>
      <url>file:../path/to/project/target/repository</url>
    </repository>

It raises an error:
No repository found at file:/..


Using file:${project.basedir}/../ instead of file:/../ solved the issue
